# $2xyy' = x^2-y^2$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this homogeneous equation (I believe it's homogeneous) and the farther I can get is:

1. $$2xyy' = x^2-y^2$$
2. $$y' = \frac{x}{2y} - \frac{y}{2x}$$

So, from here, I need explanations on how do I get to the form:
$$y' = f(\frac xy)$$

Thanks guys!

Comment: If you think it is homogeneous you can try the substitution y = ux, and see where it takes you.  If you end up with a separable equation, great, and if not, then it wasn't homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{x = \alpha\tilde{x}}$ and $\ds{y = \beta\,\tilde{y}}$. Then,
>   $$
> 2xyy'=x^2 - y^{2}\implies
> 2\tilde{x}\,\tilde{y}\,\tilde{y}' = \pars{\alpha \over \beta}^{2}\tilde{x}^{2} - \tilde{y}^{2}
> $$

The equation is invariant under the above scaling whenever $\ds{\alpha = \pm\beta}$. It means,
$$
{x \over \tilde{x}} = \pm\,{y \over \tilde{y}}\implies
{\tilde{y} \over \tilde{x}} = \pm\,{y \over x}
$$

It suggests the change of variables $\ds{u \equiv {y \over x} \implies y = ux}$.
Namely,
\begin{align}
&2x\pars{ux}\pars{u'x + u} = x^{2} - \pars{ux}^{2} \implies
2xuu' + 2u^{2} = 1 - u^{2} \implies
{2u \over 1 - 3u^{2}}\totald{u}{x} = {1 \over x}
\end{align}
Moreover,
\begin{align}
&-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 - 3u^{2}} = \ln\pars{x} + \ln\pars{\mbox{C}}
\,,\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{C is an integration constant}~}
\\[5mm]
\ln\pars{C} & = \ln\pars{\bracks{1 - 3 u^{2}}^{1/3}x}\implies
C = \pars{1 - 3\,{y^{2} \over x^{2}}}^{1/3}x \implies
\bbx{\ds{y = \pm\,{\root{x^{3} - C^{3}} \over \root{3}x^{1/2}}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You could treat $2xyy'=x^2-y^2$ as homogeneous (after a bit of algebra). But this is an exact equation:
$$(-x^2+y^2)+2xyy'=0 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad (-x^2+y^2)dx+2xy\,dy=0$$
You have $P=-x^2+y^2$ and $Q=2xy$. Notice that $P_y=2y=Q_x$. Thus this is exact.

$\int P\,dx = -\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+xy^2+C_1(y)$ and $\int Q\,dy = xy^2+C_2(x)$. Therefore, $-\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+xy^2=C$ is the general (implicit) solution. Solving for $y$ is easy. :)

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. Did not see it this way. Thanks!